# unity3d: How to register custom document kind and open it by my application?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, document, associate

I need to register my own document type, for example ".mydoc" and associate it with my Unity3D application in the iOS and Android. For example if someone send my email with something.mydoc file I need to be able to tap on the file and system will prompt to open this file with my application.

I need to do the same thing as here:http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app but in my Unity3d application for iOS and Android. I need to be able to open attachments in the emails by my application. Any ideas how to do it in Unity3d?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43675/C-FileAssociation-Class) will get you started?

Comment: Unforunately this is for Windows only. I need something like this for iOS and Androroid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application

Does that help at all?